# Vanishing integral and lower bound of cosh

Tags: complex-analysis, inequality, hyperbolic-functions

I want to show 
$$\lim_{R\to\infty}\int_\gamma f(z)\ \text{d}z=\lim_{R\to\infty}\int_\gamma\frac{e^{-ikz}}{\cosh(z)}\text{d}z = 0$$
for 
$$ \gamma(t) = R + it \qquad     t \in [0, \pi] $$
and some $k \in \mathbb{R}$ 
My idea is to prove that 
$$ \lim_{R\to\infty}\left|\int_\gamma\frac{e^{-ikz}}{\cosh(z)}\text{d}z\right|\le\lim_{R\to\infty}\int_\gamma\frac{|e^{-ikz}|}{|\cosh(z)|}\text{d}z\le 0 $$
What I already got is
$$ |e^{-ikz}| \le |e^{ky}| \le |e^{k\pi}| \le C $$
My attempt to estimate a useful lower bound of $|\cosh(z)|$ wasn't successful. 
 
 Do I have to evaluate the integral more properly to find the upper bound of $f(z)$ or is there another solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that using the addition angle formula

$$\cosh(R+it)=\cosh(R)\cos(t)+i\sinh(R)\sin(t)$$

we have $|\cosh(R+it)|=\sqrt{\cosh^2(R)\cos^2(t)+\sinh^2(R)\sin^2(t)}$.

Then, using the identities $\cosh^2(z)-\sinh^2(z)=1$ and $\cos^2(z)+\sin^2(z)=1$, we can write

$$\begin{align}
\left|\int_\gamma \frac{e^{-ikz}}{\cosh(z)}\,dz\right|&=\left|\int_0^\pi \frac{e^{-ik(R+it)}}{\cosh(R+it)}\,i\,dt\right|\\\\
&\le \int_0^\pi \frac{e^{kt}}{|\cosh(R)\cos(t)+i\sinh(R)\sin(t)|}\,dt\\\\
&=\int_0^\pi \frac{e^{kt}}{\sqrt{\cosh^2(R)-\sin^2(t)}}\,dt\\\\
&\le \frac{\pi e^{k\pi}}{\sqrt{\cosh^2(R)-1}}\\\\
&\to 0\,\,\text{as}\,\,R\to \infty
\end{align}$$

And we are done!

Comment: Now I see! Thanks a lot!

Comment: You're welcome!  My pleasure.